# Git merge halfway (not the whole branch)

Tags: git, merge

I have main branch and development branch, every time I merge from main branch I have to resolve

1. same merge conflicts I did last time
2. newer merge conflicts

I'm ok to resolve newer merge conflicts but every time I merge I have to resolve all old once since my main branch has different code than developer branch.

Is there any way we can merge only new commits and skip the old once? I do not prefer cherry picking because there are many commits happening on main branch and cherry picking is lengthy process.

Comment: Are you squash-or-rebase merging?

Comment: I'm using git merge without squash

Comment: If you are _really_ merging, then you should **not** see old conflicts show up....  check the output of `git merge-base` using the 2 branches that you are dealing with.... if it points to a very old commit that belongs to the main branch instead of the last merged commit from the development branch (which is what you would expect if you were _really_ merging) then you are not creating _real_ merges but doing a squash or a rebase.

Comment: Or you are throwing away the earlier merge in some other way (`git reset --hard` perhaps).

Comment: While resolving the merge conflicts I always accept the code on developer branch, next merge it will show the same conflict.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why it happens to you but you might use [rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) (reuse recorded resolution) that records resolutions of merge conflicts so that when the same conflict arises later, Git can automatically resolve it for you using the previously recorded resolution.

To enable rerere, you need to set the following configuration:

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

Once enabled, whenever you resolve a conflict and successfully complete the merge, Git will store the conflict resolution information. The next time you encounter the same conflict, Git will automatically apply the previously recorded resolution.

Comment: I was looking for something like this, Thanks I will try this.

Comment: @RickSanchez Cool! Let us know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this below steps with your terminal.

git branch enter (command)
then
git merge [source branch] [target branch]

your whole code will be merged

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).